# NavigateUrl on Repeater ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a table in DB:

```
NOTICE(NUM,TITLE,CONTENT)
```

I use Repeater Control in ASP to show all the notices in DB, like:

```
+----------+------------+|
|title1        (readmore)|
|
|title2        (readmore)|
|
|title3        (readmore)|
......
+------------------------+
```

All I want is:  I read a `"title"` then I clicked on `(readmore)`, the new page will be opened ( show detail's notice) with the "content" of that notice. How can I assign the `num` of notice without display it to define the notice in next page?

I just assign the title to property Text of a `Label ID="TITLE"` because I want to show the title of each notice.

All information I want to show in the this page is: `title` and the `readmore`( link to the next page). So that I don't know how to assign the num

My asp page: notice.asp

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepDetails" runat="server" >
<HeaderTemplate>
<table style="  width:565px" cellpadding="0" class="borber">
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="Title" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TITLE") %>'  /> 
</td>
<td>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" > (readmord)</asp:HyperLink>
</td>
</tr>    
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

My C# code:notice.asp.cs

```
 private void BindRepeaterData()
    {
        string sql = "select num,title from NOTICE";
        DataTable ds = l.EXECUTEQUERYSQL(sql);
        RepDetails.DataSource = ds;
        RepDetails.DataBind();

    }
```

And the next page: detailnotice.asp.cs

```
private void GetNotice()
    {
        string sql = "select * from NOTICE where num=" ;// num= the num of notice I choose in notice.asp page.
    }
```

How can I assign a num in Label without display it? What property of Label Control or I should use a other Control ?

Hope you understand what I say. If you don't, please ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi you can ues anchor tag in place of hyper link button. you can pass num in the query string to the detail page.

```
<a href='detailpage.aspx?id=<%#Eval("NUM") %>'> (readmord)</a>
```

On details page you can get query string value and fetch details from database.

```
   int myKey = 0;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
    {
        myKey = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        // Use myKey to retrieve record from database
    }
```

Comment: thanks you, in detail page, how can I recieve the id, I mean the syntax. Cause I've done it by pHp code, and I'm a new to ASP.net

Answer (score 3):

Basically the same as Sain but using the NavigateURL

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("NUM","~/detailpage.aspx?id={0}") %>' > (readmord)</asp:HyperLink>
```